# Port forwarding on Huawei D105 mobile router

Tags: router, port-forwarding

A week ago I changed my old (wall-connected) router to a mobile router – Huawei D105. I got a home server set up on a separate computer, and I just can't find a way to forward standard HTTP requests to that computer.

I've set up port forward settings to the internally used IP address (on port 80), but to no effect. I've also tried enabling DMZ, which (as far as I understand) should forward *all* requests to the given IP – still no results.

I have been searching for answers and trying different approaches, and frustration is growing.
What am I missing?

Comment: do you know for a fact that your ISP allows you to use Port 80?

Comment: DMZ does not forward all requests blindly, just most, it is still technically firewalled. Do you have a cable/adsl modem as well? if so, is it router or bridged?